# Does 10m * 0.1m equal 1m in C#?

Tags: c#, decimal, precision

The code snippet

```
decimal one1 = 10m * 0.1m;
decimal one2 = 10m / 10m;
Console.WriteLine($"{one1}, {one2}, {one1 == one2}");
```

produces the output:

```
1.0, 1, True
```

Why does the first number print with a decimal point while the second number does not. If the answer lies in the fact that the decimal type does not have the precision to fully represent `0.1`, then why does the equality operator return true?

Comment: [FYI](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRiqQLIAUAlLfY/wBMYYAJYBbAIYAbUhAB2MHKQC8pHAAYxpAFSl1AOhxiA3H34MhoyTPkwsKtZtIB6RybPmMOAJwcAJABENLY4AL4ANLS2WBFRCkrKqtGhAVymBPyhhKFAA==)

Comment: `decimal` does not lack precision. It's probably keeping the `.0` in the first one because one of the operands had a decimal point in it.

Comment: Oh, and as you can clearly see from the output you've posted yourself - `1.0` is equal to `1`.

Comment: The binary representation of a Decimal value consists of a 1-bit sign, a 96-bit integer number, and a scaling factor used to divide the 96-bit integer and specify what portion of it is a decimal fraction. .... The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

Comment: The decimal type remembers the number of significant digits. You can force the type to discard that information with `value / 1.000000000000000000000000000000000m`.

Comment: It seems like the compiler truncates zeroes after the . for division if the left side of the / has the same or fewer decimal digits (after the .) as the right side of the / (if there are more it removes some of the zeroes). I have no idea _why_ it does that. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRiqQLIAUAlLfY/wBMYYAJYBbAIYAbUhAB2MLKQC8pHAAZ1Y0gCpS6gHTqcYgNx9+DIaMkz5MHBJVqjm7QHoXb8wUuNr4tKyCjjAzjiuHl5aPn5WwoF2IWDhRlER3haWAbbBDgLh6ZGxcRg4AJwcACQARDT2jgC+NVwlfmWVtfUhwM2tWfwd1XUNYH1tlkNdDQLjA4xTIwpYc76MjYSNQA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point numbers are a complicated concept and made of 3 separate parts which store the information you would consider to be a number.

Additionally, how a compiler and computer architecture treats a floating point number is also not obvious. There are some very strange quirks when it comes to these types of numbers in general; how they store precision; what numbers they can deal with, and how the compiler and CPU does mathematics with them.

However, the reason you are getting different values is actually down to what is being stored for that number. They are in fact not the same *bits and bytes* in memory. The same number can be stored in multiple different ways, and may get there from different types of calculations (as you have shown).

Let's have a look

```
decimal one1 = 10m * 0.1m;
decimal one2 = 10m / 10m;

int[] bits = decimal.GetBits(one1);

Console.WriteLine("{0,31} {1,10:X8}{2,10:X8}{3,10:X8}{4,10:X8}", one1, bits[3], bits[2], bits[1], bits[0]);

int[] bits2 = decimal.GetBits(one2);

Console.WriteLine("{0,31} {1,10:X8}{2,10:X8}{3,10:X8}{4,10:X8}", one2, bits2[3], bits2[2], bits2[1], bits2[0]);
```

**Output**

```
                        1.0   00010000  00000000  00000000  0000000A
                          1   00000000  00000000  00000000  00000001
```

As you can see, they actually have a significantly different binary layout which means a different mantissa and scaling factor that represent the same thing.

As for the extra 0's when calling `ToString()`, the compiler knows about the significant zeros, they are part of the make up of the number and preserved based on their scales.

Luckily the *CLR* and *architecture* is smart enough to tell the difference.

Comment: So `10` with a scaling factor of `1` vs `1` with a scaling factor of `0`

Comment: @MartinSmith exactly :), your comment was prefect in that respect

Comment: Good job explaining the difference between `one1` and `one2`, but I think the OP's question was about what's causing that difference in the first place...

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks, yeah that would be a deep div into how a cpu does the math on floating point numbers :/ though I can probably add a bit more to help in that respect and to use more precise language

Comment: That the results of divisions and multiplications of `decimal`s by ten are exact (and hence the results of the two values in this case are equal) has nothing to do with luck -- this is what the type is designed for, and the compiler and CLR are behaving according to their specifications.

Comment: Yes, that's why I've only posted a short comment with a conjecture... There are depths that I will not be dragged to :-)

Comment: It would also be interesting to understand just *why* the internal representation differs, and then just *why* the output differs for two values which compare equal (which I find slightly disturbing). The latter seems to come from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-general-g-format-specifier): "However, if the number is a Decimal and the precision specifier is omitted, fixed-point notation is always used and **trailing zeros are preserved."**

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica nice find, and actually different to understanding i was getting from other various sources.

Comment: @mjwills and Peter - Reinstate Monica arg thanks guys! :p  now i have a ton more information to add!!!! I have a bunch of  sources, eric lippert quips and emca quotes that also illuminate what's going on